# web push with firebase ios devices

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, web-push

i have a problem with getToken function from firebase/messaging on ios platfrom in standalone application (on desktop (mac, windows) android everything is ok)
my code

```
async function subscribe(closeModal: () => void) {
  const permission = await Notification?.requestPermission();
  if (permission === 'granted') {
    const messaging = await getMessaging(firebaseApp);
    const token = await getToken(messaging);
  }
}
```

my request for token (getToken) doesn't work. i tried setTimeout its also doesn't work, but if i put getToken and messaging in window object and run getToken(messaging) from console, everything is ok.
help me please with this problem.
firebase version - 10.7.1
tried - use setTimeout, run getToken after sw register

Comment: also i have empty /firebase-messaging-sw.js file